# Looker Filter that can evaluate to more than one condition

Tags: looker

I'm trying to create a filter for my dashboard.

[image]

I need the filter to be able to evaluate to more than one condition.

For example, my logic can look like the following:

```
case
when account_age < 1 then 'populate new accounts'
when account_health < red then 'populate unhealthy accounts' 
...
end
```

So in the case where an account is new and unhealthy...I'm running into problems. The filter will only evaluate to the first match.

Meaning if the account is new, it will just populate when someone selects `populate new account` and will not appear when someone selects `populate unhealthy accounts`.

How can I create a filter that can evaluate to more than one criterion when selected?

Answer (score 1):

If you create the Looker parameter in LookML, you will be limited to single filter values

```
   parameter: healthy_selector {
    type: string
    default_value: "Very Healthy"
    allowed_value: {
      label: "Very Healthy"
      value: "Very"
    }
    allowed_value: {
      label: "Average Healthy"
      value: "Average"
    }
    allowed_value: {
      label: "Unhealthy"
      value: "Unhealthy"
    }
  }
```

However if you base the filter on a dimension in Looker, you will be able to change the parameter type to a Multiple Selection control such as a Tag List

[image: multiple selection tag list]

Which will allow you to select more than one option at once

[image: multiple selected countries]

Comment: If you use a dimension, each row can only have one value for that dimension. In my case, the dimension can actually be multiple values for a single row.