# Looker parameter/filter workaround

Tags: filter, parameters, looker-studio, looker

My data is as below-  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A21De.png)

| country | flag | enable | not |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| India | N | E | NA |
| UK | Y | E | NA |
| US | Y | E | NA |
| AUS | N | Not | Yes |
| NZ | null | null | null |
| Poland | N | E | NA |
| UAE | Y | E | NA |
| SA | N | Not | Yes |
| China | null | null | null |

I have 3 columns which should come as a filter dropdown. Fiter drop down has values flag, enable,not.

| filter | output |
| --- | --- |
| Flag | US |
| Flag | UK |
| Flag | UAE |

| filter | output |
| --- | --- |
| Enable | India |
| Enable | US |
| Enable | UK |
| Enable | Poland |
| Enable | UAE |

| filter | output |
| --- | --- |
| Not | AUS |
| Not | NZ |
| Not | SA |
| Not | China |

The condition is such that if it is enable,'E' then all countries should be listed for value 'E' . If flag is selected then, the countries should be listed for flag='Y' else 'NA' .

The issue is , if enable is checked then flag condition won't be checked and
sql: case
when ${enable} = 'E' then 'E'
when ${flag} = 'Y' then 'Live'
else 'NA' end;;
O/p :

| filter | output |
| --- | --- |
| Enable | India |
| Enable | US |
| Enable | UK |
| Enable | Poland |
| Enable | UAE |

Wrong o/p for flag -

| filter | output |
| --- | --- |
| Flag |  |

and if flag is written first then, enable condition won't be checked.

```
`sql: case when ${flag} = 'Y' then 'Live'
when ${enable} = 'E' then 'E'
else 'NA' end;;`
```

| filter | output |
| --- | --- |
| Flag | US |
| Flag | UK |
| Flag | UAE |

wrong o/p :

| filter | output |
| --- | --- |
| Enable | India |
| Enable | Poland |

The flag column is a subset of enable. So , I need all countries with flag as 'Y' to be listed in enable. How to do this in looker. All countries with flag 'Y' are by default 'Enable'

I can't paste images as my reputation is low.

I have created a sample report for understanding - https://lookerstudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/881370c9-a68c-4994-8b78-e96e4fa27cea/page/cC1YD

My issue is similar to this one
[Looker Filter that can evaluate to more than one condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73756392/looker-filter-that-can-evaluate-to-more-than-one-condition)